# SQL server SP : sometimes not to be included in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am very new to SQL Server Stored Procedures, 
This is My SP :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetBonusRunDetails]
(
  @StartDate as DATETIME,
  @EndDate as DATETIME,
   @PageNumber int,
  @PageSize int, 
   @Status int
)
AS

;WITH DataCTE AS
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Id) as RowNumber
     ,[StartDateTime]
      ,[EndDate]
     ,[Status]
     ,[ExecutionTime]
     ,[Code] , TotalRows = Count(*) OVER() 
   FROM [dbo].[BonusRun]
    WHERE ((StartDateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)  
   OR (EndDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate))
   AND (Status = @Status)
 )
```

I want that @Status condition check sometimes not to be included in WHERE clause.
How to do that ?

Edit :

is it not possible to to write some thing

```
IF @Status <= 0
 then @Status = NULL 
END IF
```

and in **where** statement

```
AND (Status = @Status OR @Status IS NULL)
```

Comment: I'll probably get flamed again, but i would probably use dynamic sql!

Comment: what instances do you want to include the @Status variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AND (Status = ISNULL(@Status, Status))
```

In this case if @Status is NULL it will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

A commonly used approach is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetBonusRunDetails]
(
  @StartDate as DATETIME,
  @EndDate as DATETIME,
   @PageNumber int,
  @PageSize int, 
   @Status int = NULL
)
AS

;WITH DataCTE AS
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Id) as RowNumber
     ,[StartDateTime]
      ,[EndDate]
     ,[Status]
     ,[ExecutionTime]
     ,[Code] , TotalRows = Count(*) OVER() 
   FROM [dbo].[BonusRun]
    WHERE ((StartDateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)  
   OR (EndDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate))
   AND (@Status IS NULL OR Status = @Status)
 )
```

**But** please be aware that this can have implications for Parameter Sniffing and the possibility of an inappropriate cached query plan.

In fact, while I always try not to use dynamic TSQL, when there are a large number of optional parameters, it is a valid approach to avoid incorrect cached plans.

Comment: Much cleaner than the CASE, can't for the life of me think why I never though to do it this way before...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found to do this would be using a case statement. Might not be the most efficient solution, but its better than writing the query twice, once without the where clause (if performance isn't your biggest concern)

```
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Id) as RowNumber
     ,[StartDateTime]
      ,[EndDate]
     ,[Status]
     ,[ExecutionTime]
     ,[Code] , TotalRows = Count(*) OVER() 
   FROM [dbo].[BonusRun]
    WHERE ((StartDateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)  
   OR (EndDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate))
   AND 
   (CASE WHEN (@Status IS NULL) THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE Status = @Status END);
```

I think I got that right

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
AND (@Status IS NULL OR @Status = Status)
```

So if @Status is NULL, you would return all types of Status - you could use a default value instead of NULL.